# ArgumentNullException being thrown in Decrypt method/ConvertFromBase64String

Tags: c#, encryption, argumentnullexception

To the best of my efforts I haven't been able to remedy the exceptions being thrown by my Decrypt method. On the line where it's converting data to the buffer array of bytes, an ArgumentNullException is being thrown. First I added an:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException ("Null data");
}
```

And likewise for the password, I did the same code. Then, after the same exception popped up in the if statement I changed it to the try-catch statement below. Now the exception doesn't pop up on the try-catch line, but instead on the buffer converting line in the Decrypt . I'm not really sure what the program wants since I thought the try-catch would do the trick, but I'm also pretty new to C# so I could be missing something obvious.

```
public static string Encrypt (string data, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data as string))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Null data.");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password as string))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Null password.");
        }

        using (SymmetricAlgorithm alg = GetAlgorithm(password))
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream (ms, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt (string data, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(data);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Null data.");
        }

        try
        {
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(password);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Null password.");
        }

        using (SymmetricAlgorithm alg = GetAlgorithm(password))
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(data);//This is where the exception occurs
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            buffer = ms.ToArray();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
     }
```

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` returns true or false. Why would you expect that to throw an exception?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `try/catch` blocks in place of `if` statements?  The two structures do *very* different things.

Comment: Do the same logic in decrypt as your do for encrypt (with the if statements instead of Try ... Catch.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. Using the if's as Encrypt does ends up coming up with an ArgumentNullException on the line with the if statement itself, which I've been trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

This code does absolutely nothing:

```
try
{
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(data);
}
catch
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Null data.");
}
```

This is because `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` doesn't throw an exception.  It returns a `bool`.  But you're not doing anything with that returned value.  Whatever is returned is simply discarded when the statement ends.

So if `data` is `null` then you're going to get an exception when you try to use it later in the method:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
```

Your other method already checks for `null` values correctly.  So why not use that same approach?

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    throw new ArgumentException("Null data.");
```

---

As a general note, don't use `try/catch` blocks for application logic.  Those are for catching and handling exceptions.  If you just need to check whether or not a condition is true, use an `if` statement.  Additionally, `catch` blocks which ignore the actual exception they're catching are a *famously* bad idea.  It throws away meaningful exception information and makes errors much more difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Very good stuff to know in there. I do see now that using the try-catch wouldn't be the right way to about checking for a null string. but the if check being used in Decrypt the same way as Encrypt winds up with another "ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code" error being thrown on the line with the if check itself.

Comment: @gecko94: Well, that's because the method is throwing an exception.  When you throw an exception... well... an exception gets thrown.  It's the responsibility of the consuming code to handle that exception.

Comment: @gecko94 Remove "as string" from "data as string"; it's already a string.

Comment: Ah alright, I'll work on that. Thanks again guys. The "as string" was there after I read it from another source saying that might solve the issue I was having.